# How do I update a parent object if children are changed?

Tags: php, symfony

How do I update a parent object if children are changed?

I have entity City that has children Street. I would like save in City entity total kilometers of streets.

```
City
id | name    | total
1  | example | 1000

Street
id | city_id | name   | kilometers
1  | 1       | first  | 800
2  | 1       | second | 200
```

I tried Lifecycle Callbacks (PreUpdate and PostUpdate) and Doctrine listeners - preUpdate i postUpdate. Both for City, but both not are not working if I don't edit City. So if I set listeners for Street, then this is good, but listeners are executed for each edited one of streets.

I can make this in the controller, but I would like to use events.

Comment: There's no need to have the data in two places. Just sum up `kilometers` from the street table when you're fetching a `City`.

Comment: Or alternatively write a new method in the City entity that loops all streets and counts the kilometers of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the rules by yourself. In my case I have done this using a version field in the parent that is a timestamp. There is a setVersion setter that doesn't receive any parameter that updates that value with te timestamp.

Then I call this method from the children entities every time I update any field.

I use it to trigger document updates in an Elasticsearch index, managed by FosElasticaBundle.

Answer (score 0):

Like Magnus says, you could use a custom query that uses the aggregate function SUM() to get the total of kilometers from all child entities. It is just that it requires an extra query. Another approach which works fine to me is the domain model that looks like this:

```
class City {

    // ...

    public function getTotalStreetLength()
    {
        $km = 0;

        foreach($this->streets as $street)
        {
            $km += $street->getKilometers();
        }

        return $km;
    }
}
```

Nice to read: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html